# Django doesn't show text output

Tags: python, django

I have a problem.

So,
when I go to the page 'contact_list.html' I can't see text output, I only see bullets points but without text.

So, I here is my files:

contact_list.html

```
<h1>Contacts</h1>

<ul>
    {% for cantact in object_list %}
        <li class="contact">{{ contact.first_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

from contacts.models import Contact


class ListContactView(ListView):

    model = Contact
    template_name = 'contact_list.html'
```

So, maybe do you know what's wrong here?
Thank you ;)

Comment: There is a typo for contact in `{% for cantact in object_list %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "cantact" instead of "contact" in your for loop in contact_list.html.